# edit/add to jQuery Validate email method rules?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Regarding the jQuery .validate plugin, I want to add/edit/replace to the email method to accommodate two extra rules/conditions.

The email method (which can be tested here: https://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/) allows the following to pass but I want them to fail:

- test.@test.com
- test@test

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Over ride it as in the docs example https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.methods/

Comment: Or create your own with custom name using `$.validator.addMethod()`

Comment: I've found the "email" rule, so now I'm stuck with the right regex. The "email" rule is  /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/

Comment: Actually, that email rule is terrible - it allows all sorts of non-email characters!

Comment: Lots of regex to be found online for email. Find one you like and use it in over ride

Comment: FYI:  The existing `email` rule simply follows the HTML5 standard for valid email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charlietfl said, override it.

My new method is:

```
$.validator.addMethod('betterEmail', function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(value);
        }, "Please enter a valid email address.");
```

And my rules now look like this:

```
rules: {
         email:      {betterEmail: true}
       }
```